# How can I bind web.py to localhost?

Tags: python, security, wsgi, web.py

How can I bind web.py to the loopback interface?

```
app = web.application(urls, globals())
```

When I define it this way and start it, it listens on all interfaces:

```
mit@mit1 $ python ./serve.py
http://0.0.0.0:8080/
```

It should be restricted to 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the command below...

```
python ./serve.py 127.0.0.1
```

It should do the trick!

```
c:\work\web.py\test1>python code.py 127.0.0.1
http://127.0.0.1:8080/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
python ./serve.py 127.0.0.1
```

you could defined all the host you want.Just type the host IP below